# Regex to match all lines except duplicate

Tags: php, regex, pcre, preg-match-all

I have this text:

```
156.48.459.20 - - [11/Aug/2019
156.48.459.20 - - [11/Aug/2019
235.145.41.12 - - [11/Aug/2019
235.145.41.12 - - [11/Aug/2019
66.23.114.251 - - [11/Aug/2019
```

I want to match all lines that is from the current day so i made this simple regex `'/.*11\/Aug\/2019.*'`.

As you can see there's two duplicated IPs in the text, i don't want to match the duplicated lines, so i searched a bit and i found this regex: `(.).*\1` [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/IPeZjx/1) although this regex is kinda weird i tried to apply it in my current regex, so i did: `(.*11\/Aug\/2019.*)\1`, it did not worked. Could someone help?

This is my desired result:

```
156.48.459.20 - - [11/Aug/2019
235.145.41.12 - - [11/Aug/2019
66.23.114.251 - - [11/Aug/2019
```

NOTE: i'm using the function `preg_match_all()`:

```
preg_match_all('/(.*11\/Aug\/2019.*)\1/', $input_lines, $output_array);
```

Comment: Why not simply apply [array_unique()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to the result you've got now? Possible duplicate of [preg\_match\_all ensure distinct/unique results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276168/preg-match-all-ensure-distinct-unique-results). Regular expression are sometimes useful, but they are not a panacea. Always try to find a better readable solution first.

Comment: Maybe easier https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php Also `preg_grep` would be easier if it's easy to get in an array..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is pure regex a requirement?

You can use PHP to get uniques:

```
<?php
$input_lines = '156.48.459.20 - - [11/Aug/2019
156.48.459.20 - - [11/Aug/2019
235.145.41.12 - - [11/Aug/2019
235.145.41.12 - - [11/Aug/2019
66.23.114.251 - - [11/Aug/2019';

preg_match_all( '/.*11\/Aug\/2019/m', $input_lines, $output_array );

// PHP associative array abuse incoming
// Flip the array so that the values become keys and flip it back
// This guarantees that only uniques survive
$output_array[ 0 ] = array_keys( array_flip( $output_array[ 0 ] ) );

var_dump( $output_array );
```

Outputs:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [1]=>
    string(30) "156.48.459.20 - - [11/Aug/2019"
    [3]=>
    string(30) "235.145.41.12 - - [11/Aug/2019"
    [4]=>
    string(30) "66.23.114.251 - - [11/Aug/2019"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is certainly creative.... but it doesn't explain what it does, whereas `array_unique()` does.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I recall benchmarks proving this is faster by a considerable margin...

Comment: That is correct. Array_unique is actually the slowest way to get unique items. Array_column(arr, null, key) is the fastest if I recall correctly, but that makes it associative. Array_column will iterate the array once, array_flip & array_flip does two, naturally...

Comment: @Andreas I may have to pull my foot out of my mouth slightly. PHP <= 7.1.x shows better performance with `array_flip()` but PHP >= 7.2 favors `array_unique()`. I think that the main takeaway is that premature optimization is futile unless we are talking about `++$i` vs. `$i++`

Comment: @KIKOSoftware The docs aren't too far away but I'll add some comments...

Comment: In my opinion readability is always more important than "obscure" optimizations you need to explain in a comment, or look up in documentation. A nice illustration is the [CAMT format of banks](https://www.sepaforcorporates.com/swift-for-corporates/a-practical-guide-to-the-bank-statement-camt-053-format). I had to implement this, and you don't want to know how often I had to refer back to the documentation to look up things like `FrToDt`, `CdtDbtInd`, `CLAV`, etc. Everything is encoded, and this is XML! A supposedly "human readable" format.

Comment: I tested [this code](http://codepad.org/AnpS69yw) and found your solution to be roughly 4x faster in PHP Version 7.2.21. The comparison depends on the array, which might explain why your results differ. Four times faster is signification, but only when overall speed is actually a problem. As a compromise you could define a function called `array_unique_faster()` containing the `flip(flip())`, that would explain what the code does and why you use it.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware CAMT seems to be a standardized format; I don't think it's a good comparison for my "obscure optimizations". Count your blessing for not having the pleasure of programming in [ZPL](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf); just take a gander at page 134 or 151 for example.

Comment: I'm familiar with ZPL. ZPL is a lot older than CAMT. In both cases they try to save on the amount of data that needs to be transmitted or stored, which is different from your optimization. Readability suffers in both cases though.

Answer (score 1):

Its almost a 1 liner

`'~(?m)^(?:([\d.]*[- ]*\[11/Aug/2019.*)\R*(?=[\S\s]*?\1)|(?!.*\[11/Aug/2019).*\R*)~'`

[Sample](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/49a6d89b8fc2aa7ab76fad51fbd2baad9c63ba98)

Php

```
 $target = <<<'EOS'
 156.48.459.20 - - [11/Aug/2019
 156.48.459.20 - - [11/Aug/2019
 235.145.41.12 - - [11/Aug/2019
 235.145.41.12 - - [11/Aug/2019
 66.23.114.251 - - [11/Aug/2019
 66.23.114.251 - - [09/Aug/2019
 156.48.459.20 - - [11/Aug/2019
 235.145.41.12 - - [11/Aug/2019
 66.23.114.251 - - [01/Aug/2019
 66.23.114.251 - - [11/Aug/2019
 235.145.41.12 - - [11/Aug/2019
 EOS;


 $res = preg_replace ( '~(?m)^(?:([\d.]*[- ]*\[11/Aug/2019.*)\R*(?=[\S\s]*?\1)|(?!.*\[11/Aug/2019).*\R*)~', '', $target );

 echo $res."\n";
```

Output

```
156.48.459.20 - - [11/Aug/2019
66.23.114.251 - - [11/Aug/2019
235.145.41.12 - - [11/Aug/2019
```

Better view of it

```
 (?m)
 ^ 
 (?:
      ( [\d.]* [- ]* \[ 11/Aug/2019 .* )  # (1)
      \R* 
      (?= [\S\s]*? \1 )
   |  
      (?! .* \[ 11/Aug/2019 )
      .*  \R* 
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$txt = <<<'EOD'
156.48.459.20 - - [11/Aug/2019
156.48.459.20 - - [11/Aug/2019
235.145.41.12 - - [11/Aug/2019
235.145.41.12 - - [11/Aug/2019
66.23.114.251 - - [11/Aug/2019
EOD;

$url = 'data:text/plain;base64,' . base64_encode($txt);
// change this line with the url of your log file: $url = '/path/to/file.log';

$result = [];

if ( false !== $handle = fopen($url, 'r') ) {
    while ( false !== $data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ' ') ) {
        if ( $data[3] === '[11/Aug/2019' )
            $result[$data[0]] = 1;
    }
}

$result = array_keys($result);

print_r($result);
```